# Determine if these functions are injective

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Determine if the following functions are injective.
>
> $$f(x) = \frac{x}{1+x^2}$$
>
> $$g(x) = \frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$$

My answer:

$f(x) = f(y)$

$$\implies \frac{x}{1+x^2} = \frac{y}{1+y^2}$$

$$\implies x+xy^2 =y+yx^2$$

$$\implies x=y$$

Hence $f(x)$ is injective

$g(x) = g(y)$

$$\implies \frac{x^2}{1+x^2}=\frac{y^2}{1+y^2}$$

$$\implies x^2+x^2y^2=y^2+y^2x^2$$
$$\implies x^2=y^2$$
$$\implies \pm x=\pm y$$

So $g(x)$ is not injective

Comment: $f$ is not injective since $f(x)=f(1/x)$ for all nonzero $x$.

Comment: You made a really big jump here: $$x+xy^2=y+yx^2\implies x=y$$Check that, you should find that for each $x$, there are two possible values of $y$, as it does not reduce to a perfect square quadratic.

Comment: @Rubertos how does that make it injective, f(2) = 1/2?

Comment: @TheGamer It doesn't, note that $f(2)=\frac2{1+2^2}=\frac{1/2}{1+(1/2)^2}=f(1/2)$, so it isn't injective.

Comment: your last line$$x-y-xy(x-y)=0$$ and this is equivalent to $$(x-y)(1-xy)=0$$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt so the reason why its not injective is because $f(2) = \frac{1}{2}$ but $f(\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{2}{5}$

Comment: @TheGamer No. $f(2)=f(\frac 12)=\frac 25$

Comment: @TheGamer No, that is false.  $f(2)\ne\frac12$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt how did u get $f(\frac{1}{2})$

Comment: @TheGamer The answer you accepted below says $f(2)=f(\frac 12)=\frac 25$. Surely, you understood the answer before accepting?

Comment: @SahibaArora i understood the x=y or xy=1, which means x has two values, and thus it cannot be injective

Comment: @TheGamer $xy=1 \implies y=\frac 1x$. Hence, $f(x)=f(y) \implies x=y$ or $y=\frac1x$.

Comment: @SahibaArora oh k also how would i determine if a function is surjective, its same function, or do u want me to make a new post

Comment: @TheGamer That depends on the domain and co-domain. I suggest you try to do it yourself and then post it as another question if you get stuck.

Comment: @SahibaArora can u check my surjective question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2360856/determine-if-the-function-is-surjective)

Comment: Everybody has covered the first function completely, but there is an even easier way to get to the second function's result.  A function, $h(x)$, is even if $h(x)=h(-x)$ for all $x$ (when the function is defined at $x$ and $-x$).  A rational function is even if the only powers that appear are even (the converse is not true).  So the function, $g(x)$, is even.  Therefore, if $x\neq0$, we have that $g(x)=g(-x)$ so it can't be injective.

Comment: @TheGamer I had seen it earlier and thought the answers were sufficient. However, I have added an answer for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $x + xy^2 = y+yx^2$, then $(x - y) = yx^2 - xy^2 = xy(x-y)$.  This gives $(x-y)(xy-1) = 0$, hence either $x=y$ or $xy=1$. You can check that for example, $f(\frac 12) = f(2) = \frac 25$.

Hence, $f$ is not injective.

The answer to the second question is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x \neq 0$
$$f\left(\frac1x\right)=\frac{1/x}{1+1/x^2}=\frac{x}{1+x^2}=f(x)$$

Thus, $f$ is not injective. Your mistake was $x+xy^2=y+yx^2 \implies x=y$. This is certainly not true.

$$g(-2)=\frac{(-2)^2}{1+(-2)^2}=\frac{4}{1+4}=g(2)$$

Hence, $g$ is not injective.

Answer (score 2):

Where you had $x+xy^2=y+yx^2,$ you canceled $xy^2$ from one side and $yx^2$ from the other side, but those are not the same.

But the equation can be written as $yx^2 - (y^2+1) x + y = 0,$ and that is $ax^2+bx+c=0,$ where $a=y,$ $b=-(y^2+1),$ and $c=y.$

The solution for $x$ of the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ is $x = \dfrac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac\ {}}}{2a}.$

So you have $x = \dfrac{y^2+1 \pm \sqrt{(y^2+1)^2 - 4y^2}}{2y} = \dfrac{y^2+1 \pm (y^2-1)}{2y} = \Big( \dfrac 1 y \text{ or } y \Big).$

Since there are two solutions, this is not one-to-one.

Comment: yes ur right idk why i thought $xy^2 = yx^2$

Comment: $\ldots\,$and another approaches is to look at what the graph of $x\mapsto \dfrac x {1+x^2}$ looks like. It's $0$ when $x=0;$ it's positive when $x>0,$ but it approaches $0$ as $x\to\infty,$ so that means it has to go up and then come back down. Hence it fails the horizontal line test.

Comment: That works only if we know $f(x)$ is continuous over that domain.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt : No kidding. $\qquad$