# Determine if the function is surjective

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $\\f: \ \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ via $ f(x) = \frac {x}{1+x^2}$.

I know this function is not injective, but im not sure how to determine if the function is surjective or not

Comment: Hint: $2x \le 1+x^2 \iff f(x) \le 1/2\,$.

Comment: @dxiv how did u even get that

Comment: $2x \le 1+x^2$ follows from $0 \le 1 - 2x+x^2=(x-1)^2\,$ which is farily recognizable once you've seen it enough times.

Comment: @dxiv where ru getting 2x from?

Comment: @TheGamer: That was just answered for you.

Comment: @TheGamer The factor of $2$ is for completing the square $\,(x-1)^2\,$ "nicely". Then, once you proved that $\,2x \le 1+x^2\,$, just divide both sides by $\,2(1+x^2) \gt 0\,$ to get $\,f(x) \le 1/2\,$.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A function is surjective if every element has a pre-image. I will show that this function is not surjective by showing $2$ does not have a pre-image.

Indeed, if $2$ has a pre-image, say $x$ then $$\frac{x}{1+x^2}=2$$
Then $x=2+2x^2$. That is $$2x^2-x+2=0$$
As $1-4(2)(2)<0$. Therefore, this equation has no real roots. 
Hence, $f$ cannot be surjective.

Comment: I see, but how did u know 2 doesnt work

Comment: As it clear from Tsemo Aristide answer, $|f| \leq 1$.

Comment: oh cuz since f(x) is always less than 1, its surjective?

Comment: It is **not** surjective. Since $f$ does not take any value greater than $1$. Any value greater than $1$ does not have a pre-image.

Comment: oops i meant that

Answer (score 2):

In order to show that $f$ is surjective, you must show that for any $y\in\Bbb R,$ there is some $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $f(x)=y.$ That is, we must be able to solve $$\frac{x}{1+x^2}=y$$ for $x$ and find that $x\in\Bbb R.$ The quadratic formula will come in handy in your attempts to do so.

Comment: since u cant solve this, its surjective?

Comment: If you can't solve it for arbitrary real $y,$ then it is *not* **surjective**. That doesn't make it injective, however, as you've already seen that it isn't injective.

Comment: but wouldnt using quadratic make it complicated

Comment: Not overly. I suppose that's subjective, though. Try converting the above into a quadratic equation in $x,$ and see what you can come up with.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $|x|\leq 1$, you have $|x|\leq 1\leq 1+x^2$ implies that $|f(x)|\leq 1$.

Suppose that $|x|\geq 1$, then $|x|\leq |x|^2\leq 1+x^2$ implies that $|f(x)|\leq 1$.